# Is pytest tmpdir only associated with function parameters?

Tags: python, pytest

Is there a way to write test methods of a class using pytest fixture tmrdir? In the documentation, it specifies that it can be used with a function. 
https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/tmpdir.html

If there is a way to pass tmpdir parameter for test methods in a class, could you please share an example?

I have tried the following thing, but I am getting an error such as:
"

> test_method() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)"

My code:

```
import pytest

class class_test(TestCase):

    def test_method(self,tmpdir):
        # code
```

Please help.

Comment: You can't pass fixtures as test parameters in `unittest` test classes, only in test functions. Check out [Using autouse fixtures and accessing other fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/unittest.html#using-autouse-fixtures-and-accessing-other-fixtures) for an example of applying fixtures in `unittest` test classes via autousing, it happens to be the `tmpdir` usage.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @hoefling.  I used the code from the first snippet from https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/unittest.html#using-autouse-fixtures-and-accessing-other-fixtures as it is. Even after that, it doesn't seem to work. What else can I be missing?

Answer (score 1):

As written in the documentation [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/unittest.html#using-autouse-fixtures-and-accessing-other-fixtures) you have to add the **tmpdir** parameter on the ***initdir*** function. 
In this way the ***initdir*** fixture function will be used for all methods of the class

Example:

```
import unittest
import pytest

   class Test_Temp(unittest.TestCase):
      @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
      def initdir(self, tmpdir):
          tmpdir.chdir()  # change to pytest-provided temporary directory
          tmpdir.join("samplefile.ini").write("# testdata")

      def test_file content(self):
          with open('samplefile.ini', 'r') as f:
             assert f.read() == '# testdata'   //True
```